# I have created a spring boot application

Tags: spring-data-jpa, h2

I have added dependency for h2 in memory database in my pom.xml but i have not configured the h2 database properties in my application.properties but still my jpa class are getting created in h2 database, can someone tell how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is due to auto-configuration feature of spring boot

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html

> Spring Boot auto-configuration attempts to automatically configure your Spring application based on the jar dependencies that you have added. For example, if HSQLDB is on your classpath, and you have not manually configured any database connection beans, then Spring Boot auto-configures an in-memory database.
>
> You need to opt-in to auto-configuration by adding the @EnableAutoConfiguration or @SpringBootApplication annotations to one of your @Configuration classes.